# need help in this js when im run this is what the out put. in tutorial its perfectly fine but in mine its not

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**This is the code**

import React from 'react';
import {CssBaseline, Grid} from '@material-ui/core';

```
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import List from './components/List/List';
import Map from './components/Map/Map';
 

const App = () => {
    return (
       <> 
            <CssBaseline />
            <Header />
            <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                <Grid items xs={12} md={4}>
                    <List />
                </Grid>
                <Grid items xs={12} md={8}>
                <Map />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**OUTPUT**

Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/caban/Kodego File/travel_miniproject/src/App.js: Unexpected token (11:9)

```
 9 | const App = () => {
  10 |     return (
> 11 |         <>
     |          ^
  12 |             <CssBaseline />
  13 |             <Header />
  14 |             <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ width: '100%' }} >
```

@ ./src/index.js 13:11-27

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the version you're using doesn't support ["empty tag" fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html).  You can use the longer, more explicit version:

```
<React.Fragment> 
  <CssBaseline />
  <!-- etc. -->
</React.Fragment>
```